# How do i correctly ask a collectionview to resize its Cells on Orientation Change?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple UICollectionView and I want to change cell size when the width of the view is too large.

1/ I do the job in siZeForItemAt

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let collectionWidth = collectionView.frame.width
    var width:CGFloat

    if collectionWidth > 500 {
        width = collectionWidth / 4 - 8
        print("4 DE LARGE")
    } else {
        width = collectionWidth / 3 - 8
        print("3 DE LARGE")
    }

    return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
}
```

2/ I override viewWillTransition to call invalidateLayout on my collectionView so my collectionView will be redraw at evry orientation Change.

```
 override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

                self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

}
```

On the first orientation Change it works great. but if i go to another view, come back to my initial view and go back to the previous orientation, the sizeForItemAt is not called... And the size of my cell don't change... I don't understand why... am i doing somthing wrong ?

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal code example containing what you tried and what didn't work. Your description is rather cryptic.

Comment: Sorry, here is my code, i edit my first message to show it

Comment: I made a new test. If i stay on the view with the collectionView, there is no problem. Orientation changes are correctly handled by viewWillTransition witch update the collectionView Layout. The problem occurs when I change orientation, go to another view, come back and change orientation to the previous one. I still don't understand why. Any idears ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue fixed it by relating the width with UIScreen. In my case the cell expands from left to right.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 150)
}
```